# gcc won't compile missing sys/cdefs.h

Tags: c++, c, gcc, libgcc

Trying to compile gcc on an armhf embedded device but it halts when trying to compile libgcc with xgcc saying it can't find sys/cdefs.h

libc6 and libc6-dev are already installed and cdefs.h can be found at /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/

how do i add /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf to the xgcc include path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to add `--with-float=hard` to the configure line.

This is because MULTIARCH_DIRNAME is defined based on the with-float configuration option

`MULTIARCH_DIRNAME = $(call if_multiarch,arm$(ARM_EB)-linux-gnueabi$(if $(filter hard,$(with_float)),hf))`

As pointed out by the kind fellows at  [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77447)

Answer (score 1):

add the parameter: `-I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf`
 to the compile statement

Comment: that would work but i would have to dig into the configure script to do that right? was hoping for an easier way out